# Java cannot resolve symbol xsd file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have the following .xsd file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://soapexercise.plonca.sri.pja.edu/employees"
           targetNameSpace="http://soapexercise.plonca.sri.pja.edu/employees"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="employeeDto">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="birthDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="job" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="getEmployeesResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="employees" type="tns:employeeDto" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

IntelliJ says that `tns:employeeDto` cannot be resolved. If I try running `jaxb2:xjc` plugin on the file I get the following stack trace: https://pastebin.com/CfseWE23. What should I do to make `tns:employeeDto` resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetNameSpace` should be `targetNamespace`. The attribute capitalization is wrong, and invalid.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Schema_details